# Где ошибка в логике вывода галереи значков?

Tags: c#, unity3d, gallery

У меня галерея значков отображается, с нынешнем кодом, тремя способами:

Нормально
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В одну линию
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и криво
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как переделать код, чтоб отображалась только как на первой картинке ?

Сам код :

```
void iconObjMap(bool boolval = true)
{

    EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();

    if (myList != null && myList.Count > 1 && myList[1] != null)
    {
        if (treeBool == false)
        {
            //Profiler.BeginSample("MyPieceOfCode");

            _m_Pos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(_m_Pos, false, true, GUILayout.Width(LeftSection.width), GUILayout.Height(LeftSection.height - 100));
            int count = 0;
            bool checkHorizontal = false;
            int checkbrgin = 0;
            for (int l = 0; l < myList.Count;)
            {
                // Texture2D myOtherTex = LoadTexture(myList[l].url_texture);
                // Texture tex = myOtherTex as Texture;
                double countColumn = Math.Floor((double)LeftSection.width / TextureObj[l].width);
                if (boolval) { if (false == myList[l].toggle) { goto Next; } } else { if (true == myList[l].toggle) { goto Next; } }
                if (-1 == tempLayer && -1 == tempType)
                {
                    goto Build;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (myList[l].layer_number == tempLayer && myList[l].geometry_type == tempType)
                    {
                        goto Build;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (myList[l].layer_number == tempLayer && tempType == -1)
                        {
                            goto Build;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (myList[l].geometry_type == tempType && tempLayer == -1)
                            {
                                goto Build;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                goto Next;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            Build:
                if (l % (int)countColumn == 0 || checkbrgin == 0)
                {
                    count = 0;
                    checkHorizontal = true;
                    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                    EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
                    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                    EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
                    myList[l].toggle = EditorGUILayout.ToggleLeft(myList[l].key, myList[l].toggle);
                    if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
                    {
                        if (myList[l].toggle == true)
                        {
                            string stringtoggle = "UPDATE ObjectMap SET toggle=" + myList[l].toggle + " WHERE  id_ObjM=" + myList[l].iddb + "";
                            ODBtemp.UpdateSELECTObj(stringtoggle);
                            Debug.Log("myList[l].key=" + myList[l].key + "toggle true");
                        }
                        else if (myList[l].toggle == false)
                        {
                            string stringtoggle = "UPDATE ObjectMap SET toggle=" + myList[l].toggle + " WHERE  id_ObjM=" + myList[l].iddb + "";
                            ODBtemp.UpdateSELECTObj(stringtoggle);
                            Debug.Log("myList[l].key=" + myList[l].key + "toggle false");
                        }
                    }
                    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
                    if (GUILayout.Button(TextureObj[l]))
                    {
                        SelectObject(l);
                    }
                    EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
                }
                else
                {
                    EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
                    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                    EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
                    myList[l].toggle = EditorGUILayout.ToggleLeft(myList[l].key, myList[l].toggle);
                    if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
                    {
                        if (myList[l].toggle == true)
                        {
                            string stringtoggle = "UPDATE ObjectMap SET toggle=" + myList[l].toggle + " WHERE  id_ObjM=" + myList[l].iddb + "";
                            ODBtemp.UpdateSELECTObj(stringtoggle);
                            Debug.Log("myList[l].key=" + myList[l].key + "toggle true");
                        }
                        else if (myList[l].toggle == false)
                        {
                            string stringtoggle = "UPDATE ObjectMap SET toggle=" + myList[l].toggle + " WHERE  id_ObjM=" + myList[l].iddb + "";
                            ODBtemp.UpdateSELECTObj(stringtoggle);
                            Debug.Log("myList[l].key=" + myList[l].key + "toggle false");
                        }
                    }
                    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
                    if (GUILayout.Button(TextureObj[l]))
                    {
                        SelectObject(l);
                    }
                    EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
                    count++;
                    if (count == (int)countColumn - 1 || l == myList.Count - 1)
                    {
                        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
                        checkHorizontal = false;
                    }
                }
                checkbrgin++;

            Next:
                if (checkHorizontal == true && l == myList.Count - 1) { EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal(); break; }
                l++;

            }

            EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
            Debug.Log("Количество объектов:"+checkbrgin);
            //Profiler.EndSample();
        }
        else
        {
            m_SimpleTreeView.OnGUI(new Rect(0, 60, LeftSection.width, LeftSection.height - 80));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        GUILayout.Label("Объекты не определены, определите объекты.");
    }

    treeBool = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(0, LeftSection.height - 20, 100, 20), treeBool, "Дерево");

    EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
}
```

Comment: Как минимум обойтись без `goto`, из-за этого и кучи layout групп можно таких дел наворотить...

Comment: Помница препад ещё на первом занятии, ещё до того, как чему-либо научить предупредил, что за `goto` расстрел на месте. Прошло больше 10 лет и я впервые увидел goto =D lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkHorizontal == true`... Серьёздно? просто `if (checkHorizontal)` не хватает?

---

Могу ошибаться, но насколько я понял, надо убрать вышеупомянуты if и добавить

```
if (l == myList.Count-1) { 
    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
} else if (checkHorizontal) {
    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
}
```

И так-же поскольку математика подсчёта `countColumn` из превидённого кода абсолютна не ясна. `if (count == (int)countColumn - 1` видится мутной. Вроде проще типа
`checkHorizontal = count == 10;` вместо этого if который почему-то в последнем элементе листа закрывает горизональ при том что она ещё раз будет закрыта в следующем if по тем-же причинам. Если я не ошибся то получается shitcode какой-то.

---

И простит вас бог программирования за форматирование "новая строка-операционная скобка"... читать код такова объёма в такой рамке при этом формате это challenge.

Comment: c if , у меня, Старая привычка так писать. Ваш пост натолкнул , на правильную мысль ....Примите мои изменения в вопросе (я только код добавлю)

Comment: countColumn - это длинна секции, поделённая на длину иконки = количеству в строке значков

Answer (score 0):

```
   void iconObjMap(bool boolval = true)
    {
        EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
        if (myList != null && myList.Count > 1 && myList[1] != null)
        {
            if (treeBool == false)
            {
                //Profiler.BeginSample("MyPieceOfCode");
                _m_Pos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(_m_Pos, false, true, GUILayout.Width(LeftSection.width), GUILayout.Height(LeftSection.height - 100));
                bool checkHorizontal = false;
                int countshowobj = 0;
                for (int l = 0; l < myList.Count;)
                {
                    double countColumn = Math.Floor((double)LeftSection.width / TextureObj[l].width) - 2;
                    if (boolval) { if (false == myList[l].toggle) { goto Next; } } else { if (true == myList[l].toggle) { goto Next; } }
                    if (-1 == tempLayer && -1 == tempType)
                    {
                        goto Build;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (myList[l].layer_number == tempLayer && myList[l].geometry_type == tempType)
                        {
                            goto Build;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (myList[l].layer_number == tempLayer && tempType == -1)
                            {
                                goto Build;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (myList[l].geometry_type == tempType && tempLayer == -1)
                                {
                                    goto Build;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    goto Next;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                Build:
                    if (countshowobj == 0)
                    {
                        checkHorizontal = true;
                        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                        SetSection(myList[l], l);
                    }
                    else if (countshowobj % (int)countColumn == 0)
                    {
                        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
                        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                        SetSection(myList[l], l);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SetSection(myList[l], l);
                    }
                    countshowobj++;

                Next:
                    if (checkHorizontal == true && l == myList.Count - 1) { EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal(); break; }
                    l++;

                }
                EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
                // Debug.Log("Количество объектов:"+countshowobj);
                // Profiler.EndSample();
            }
            else
            {
                m_SimpleTreeView.OnGUI(new Rect(0, 60, LeftSection.width, LeftSection.height - 80));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            GUILayout.Label("Объекты не определены, определите объекты.");
        }
        treeBool = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(0, LeftSection.height - 20, 100, 20), treeBool, "Дерево");
        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
    }
    void SetSection(mapObject mapObj, int index)
    {
        EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();

        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        mapObj.toggle = EditorGUILayout.ToggleLeft(mapObj.key, mapObj.toggle);
        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            if (mapObj.toggle)
            {
                string stringtoggle = "UPDATE ObjectMap SET toggle=" + mapObj.toggle + " WHERE  id_ObjM=" + mapObj.iddb + "";
                ODBtemp.UpdateSELECTObj(stringtoggle);
                Debug.Log("mapObj.key=" + mapObj.key + "toggle true");
            }
            else if (mapObj.toggle == false)
            {
                string stringtoggle = "UPDATE ObjectMap SET toggle=" + mapObj.toggle + " WHERE  id_ObjM=" + mapObj.iddb + "";
                ODBtemp.UpdateSELECTObj(stringtoggle);
                Debug.Log("mapObj.key=" + mapObj.key + "toggle false");
            }
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        if (GUILayout.Button(TextureObj[index]))
        {
            SelectObject(index);
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
    }
```